# How do I make my subs() not change inputdata in Vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

When I call a sub and pass a variable, after the sub ends the passed variable is changed. How do I make it not do that?

So in the example the debug.print should be 3 not 8

```
sub main()
  i = 3
  SomeSub i
  debug.print i
end sub

sub SomeSub(j)
  j=j+5
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the ByVal keyword to pass on the value

```
Sub SomeSub(ByVal j As Long)
  j = j + 5
End Sub
```

Further [reading](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-objects/#Using_ByRef_and_ByVal)

> **Using ByRef and ByVal**
>
> When we pass a simple variable to a procedure we can pass using ByRef
> or ByVal.
>
> ***ByRef*** means we are passing the address of the variable. If the
> variable changes in the procedure the original will also be changed.
>
> ***ByVal*** means we are creating a copy of the variable. If the variable
> changes in the procedure the original will not be changed.